# How can I view my friend's Tiny Death Star tower?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Tiny Death Star is a Star Wars version of Tiny Tower.  In Tiny Tower, I can easily view my friend's tower.  Is this possible in Tiny Death Star?  If so how?

Example: Here is a screenshot of my Friends also playing Tiny Tower (I can then click on their tower to view it).

[image: "Friends" screen of Tiny Tower, showing three buildings]

I couldn't find the option / similar feature in Tiny Death Star when I looked.  Have I missed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mention of this feature in the [feature list on the game's website](http://starwars.com/explore/video-games/tiny-death-star/), and it definitely isn't available within the game, so unfortunately it doesn't appear to be available.

Comment: Maybe they thought there can only be one ultimate power in the universe, so looking at other ones would break that illusion.

Answer (score 0):

For a brief moment, there was a social media button in the middle space of the menu page.  But, it was taken away with another update.  I know it had a share on Facebook option.